# Using HTML file as a sharepoint home page

Tags: 2013, html

I know how to convert a html file to SharePoint 2013 master page by Design Manager, but how about home page?

Can I use a html file for that?

Comment: You mean you want to convert html file to aspx or just want to use html file as home page?

Comment: I want to convert html file to aspx and use it as home page

Comment: And that HTML page would keep being a simple static HTML page, or would it behave like a normal SharePoint .aspx page (with ribbon, navigations, menus, etc.) ?

Comment: I want it to be like a normal sharepoint page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Design Manager.

Import the html file as a page layout. Choose the page layout to be of type Welcome Page.

Now you can create a new Page in SharePoint and set it as the home page.